# how to do nested loop using apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I have a data frame like this:

```
text,                pos
No thank you.        [(No, DT), (thank, NN), (you, PRP)]
They didn't respond  [(They, PRP), (didn't, VBP), (respond, JJ)]
```

I want o apply a function on `pos` and save the result in a new column. So the output would look like this:

```
text,                pos                                           score
No thank you.        [(No, DT), (thank, NN), (you, PRP)]        [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [], [0.5, 0.0, 0.45]]
They didn't respond  [(They, PRP), (didn, VBP), (respond, JJ)]  [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [], [0.75, 0.0, 0.25]]
```

So the function ***return a list for each tuple in the list*** (but the implementation of the function is not the point here, for that I just call `get_sentiment`).
I can do it using the nested loop but I didn't like it. I want to do it using a more pythonic and Pandas Dataframe way:

This is what I have tried so far:

`df['score'] = df['pos'].apply(lambda k: [get_sentiment(x,y) for j in k for (x,y) in j])`

However, it raises this error:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

There is a couple of question in so but the answers was in R.

***for more clarity:***

`get_sentiment` function is a function in `NLTK` that assigns a list of score to each word (The list is `[positive score, negative score, objectivity score]`). Overall, I need to apply that function on top of the `pos` column of my Dataframe.

Comment: What is the reference or references for the values in those list? for instance, how do you determine that `(No, DT)` converts to `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]`?

Comment: @ashkangh I have called `get_sentiment` function of `NLTK`. So what it does, it assign a score to each word. But I don't need that part as the function already works perfectly. I don't know how to apply that function on top of `pos` column in my Dataframe.

Comment: @ashkangh The list is `[positive score, negative score, objectivity score]`. This is the list assign to each tuple. But I feel we don't need this detail as my problem is more general, and is how to incorporate two nested loop and apply.

Comment: Assuming the ```get_sentiment``` function does exactly what you say - takes a tuple as it's only argument and returns a list of scores, maybe something like this would work? ```df['score'] = df['pos'].apply(lambda k: [get_sentiment(j) for j in k])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case

```
df['score'] = df['pos'].apply(lambda k: [get_sentiment(j[0],j[1]) for j in k ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take Pandas out of the equation and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem - which is to do with the lambda itself:

```
def mock_sentiment(word, pos):
    return len(word) * 0.1, 0, len(pos) * 0.1

data = [('No', 'DT'), ('thank', 'NN'), ('you', 'PRP')]

[mock_sentiment(x, y) for j in data for (x,y) in j] # reproduces the error
```

The problem is that each `j in data` (e.g. `('No', 'DT')`) is a *single tuple* that we want to unpack into `x, y` values. By iterating `in j`, we get individual strings (`'No'` and `'DT'`) which we then attempt to unpack into `x` and `y`. This happens to work for `'No'` and `'DT'`, but not for strings of other lengths - and even then, it's not the desired result.

Since `j` is already the tuple that we want to unpack, what we want to do is unpack it *there*, by using `(x, y)` *rather than* `j` for the iteration, and not have any nested comprehension:

```
[mock_sentiment(x, y) for (x, y) in data] # works as expected
```

Consequently, *that* is what we want the lambda to give back to Pandas in the real code (substituting back in your names and the real sentiment function):

```
df['score'] = df['pos'].apply(lambda k: [get_sentiment(x, y) for (x, y) in k])
```